# changing an ng-option on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been working on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/pqLgc2dq/49/) and I know I have mistakes in it.

what I want to be able to do is to pre-populate the ng-options from the URL.

There is 9 drop menus and my best attempt was to append the split to the "id" but that didnt work. I have tried to bind to the ng-model using $scope."ng-model name" = something but because I need to set an initial value for calculations it wouldnt work. (and because the model name is the array, not an individual item in the array).

Could I ask the community for help with it.

```
 $("#loadURL").click(function () {
var checkURL = $(location).attr("href")
var fiddleURL = '   http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/waynestest/menu/links.html?&i&a&a&a&a&b&b&b&c' //temp URL for testing - delete this line on live site

//var domain = checkURL.split('&');     //use this line for live site as it will use the URL
var domain = fiddleURL.split('&');      //delete this line on live site as URL doesnt show properly on JSFiddle


//this bit is wrong as apending doesnt work for angular
        $("#loadedplatform").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[1] +'</option>')
    $("#loadedweapon").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[2] +'</option>')
    $("#loadedarmour1").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[3] +'</option>')     
    $("#loadedarmour2").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[4] +'</option>')
    $("#loadedarmour3").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[5] +'</option>')       
    $("#loadedspecial1").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[6] +'</option>')     
    $("#loadedspecial2").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[7] +'</option>')
    $("#loadedspecial3").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[8] +'</option>')
    $("#loadedtrans1").append('<option value="" selected>' + domain[9] +'</option>')   

 $scope.platform = "level 5" //this is a test to check that loadURL works but the actual ng-model is an array, it doesnt and secondly because of line 73 of this script (added so it can calculate), it changes it back
```

Comment: you need to set your parsed url as an array to $scope then access it in the html with ng-options

Comment: Is there really no better way to get this data than from the URL?  Also, appending options using JQuery is so not Angular.  Get the options into an array and bind that using ng-options.

Comment: I totally agree Jbrown, appending isnt the correct way, i have found that out. Parseing the URL is, but dont know how and because i have read so many pages, my brain is fried trying to understand it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from the URL and parse it, but you have to make sure that the URL is consistently the same. I created a way of dynamically creating `<select>` fields based on how many characters are between the `&` in the URL. You can easily modify it to meet your needs.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("TestModule", []);

  var TestController = function() {
      var vm = this;
      var fiddleURL = 'http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/waynestest/menu/links.html?&i&a&a&a&a&b&b&b&c';

      var shortURL = fiddleURL.split("&");
      
      vm.selectOptions = [{
        id: "loadedplatform",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedweapon",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedarmour1",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedarmour2",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedarmour3",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedspecial1",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedspecial2",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedspecial3",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, {
        id: "loadedtrans1",
        urlChar: "foo"
      }, ];

      for(var i = 0; i < vm.selectOptions.length; i++){
        vm.selectOptions[i].urlChar = shortURL[i + 1]; // i + 1 because shortURL at 0 contains the url before the first &. Can easily be modified to ignore this
      }
    } // End of TestController


  app.controller("TestController", [TestController]);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestModule">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="select in vm.selectOptions">
    
    <label for="{{ select.id }}">{{ select.id }}</label>
    <select id="{{ select.id }}">
      <option value="{{ select.urlChar }}" selected>{{ select.urlChar }}</option>
    </select>
    <br />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This example assumes that you want to assign the characters in the URL sequentially. If you don't then you might want to change the order of the objects in `vm.selectedOptions`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to append to certain elements in a *jQuery* fashion, you can use [AngularJS's way of doing it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Call `angular.element('someid').append('something');`